# parsing ssh-config file with regex

Tags: regex, groovy

I am having great difficulty parsing a ssh-config formatted file with regex

I wish to obtain each configuration group in the file, for example, If the string to parse is this:

```
Host myserver
 HostName somedns1
 User abcuser
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host myserver2
 HostName someotherdns2
 User yourmum
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_yourmum_rsa
Other sdofmwerf
 something some
 haha ha
Host myserver3
 HostName someotherdns23
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 User root
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/deploy.key
Host myserver4
 HostName someotherdns532
 PrefferedAuthentications publickey
 User root
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/deploy.key
```

I wish to get each group starting with the Word without a space before it, all the way up to just before the next group. This is an example of one such group:

```
Other sdofmwerf
 something some
 haha ha
```

I have tried various lookahead/behind techniques and capture groups however i am fairly new to this and have wasted a few hours trying to acheive it. I'm sorry if this is a simple case.

EDIT: I am using <s>java</s> **Groovy 2.3.6** .

*Thank you for your time!*

Comment: In which language/tool do you want this?

Comment: also I'm using groovy, so this is an example of a failed attempt: `~/(?<=[A-Z][\w\s\.\\/\n~])(?=\n\w+)[A-Z][\w\s\.\/\n~]+/`

Comment: The regexp is `/(?<=^)(\S.*?)(?=^\S|\Z)/sm`. Since it’s PCRE compliant, it might be easily adopted to java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the answers given, I decided to share mine.

```
/(?<=^)(\S.*?)(?=^\S|\Z)/sm
```

is shorter and lacks problems with `\n` is.

The parts are:

- positive lookbehind for beginning of the string
- content to be written in the separate file
- positive lookahead for the string starting with non-space, or end of input

Comment: I Like this one the best, however i had to change the syntax to `~/(?s)(?m)(?<=^)(\S.*?)(?=^\S|\Z)/` in order for it to work with groovy literal regexes. for some reason intellij does not like the modifiers at the end of the regex :S

Comment: Fine, I was glad to help. BTW you may concat modifiers like: `(?sm)` instead of `(?s)(?m)`.

Comment: check out my mods and see what you think :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to capture each block separately:

```
^(\w[\s\S]*?\w)$(?=(?:\s^\w|\s*\z))
```

- Use it with flag `m` (MULTILINE)

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yD3lR2/3)

You need to use this regex in `Matcher#find()` while loop to get each block.

Comment: `(?:\n^\w|\z))` will fail on Windows/Mac. Use `\R` for carriage return in modern PCRE implementations (while `^` perfectly fits.)

Comment: I don’t know, that’s why I mentioned “modern impls.” `^\S|\Z` is still perfectly enough.

Comment: how do you add the GLOBAL modifier in java? also, how do you specify modifiers in groovy regex literals?

Comment: You don't need global modifier in Java, it is by default global just use it in `while (matcher.find()) {...}` method. Same approach will work in Groovy also.

Comment: unfortunately this approach did not retrieve the last group for me in groovy :(

Comment: It does retrieve the last match as you can see in the demo as well.

Comment: And you're insisting on Groovy whereas you wrote in question: **EDIT: I am using java**

Comment: my apologies, I have changed my request to be groovy. It was my false assumption that the two used the same semantics. but i am now aware this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, I have edited the regex as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
(^(?!\s).*?\n(?:\s.*?(?:\n|$))*)
```

Try this.Make sure you set the correct flags.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/6

Comment: this works, however i like mudasobwa's one better :P